# Getting error in Xray while uploading JSON with Test Results from wdio cucumber json reporter

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io, jira-xray, test-results

I can't upload JSON results from wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter to xray (test execution), there's an error and I'm not sure if it's a problem with reporter package or xray?
I tried some other reporters as well but nothing was handy.

Which json-reporter will work fine with newest webdriverIO 6.10.5 ?
I want also include Sauce Labs Report links to JSON if possible.

Error message:

> Error importing execution results to database: Error de-serializing
> execution results file -> com.b.a.H: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 at
> com.b.a.b.a.v.b(Unknown Source) at com.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source) at
> com.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source) at

Stack: webdriverio, cucumber, sauce-labs, jira-xray
I am trying to import results to xray manually.

Comment: 1. can you please share the JSON report that was generated?
2. how are you submiting the results to Xray exactly? can you detail the API call you're making?

Comment: I've pasted the JSON here: https://justpaste.it/5t0fh (change names a little bit). I try to export/import manually with Xray.

Comment: Are you using Jira cloud or on premises? And exactly how did you submit the report? Which endpoint have you used?

Comment: I'm creating Test Execution manually in Xray, then, export manually cucumber feature file, execute the tests in the repository, generate the report, then manually import test results to Jira. The next step is to use a plugin and automate this process with Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. We've created an issue in our backlog and it will be handled soon.
Please track it [here](https://jira.xpand-it.com/browse/XRAY-6854).
Note that if you use the REST API it should workk fine though (or one of the CI Plugins which in turn use the REST API)

I've used [this content](https://justpaste.it/39aci), which contains minor changes so the feature is tagged with a requirement/story issue and a scenario linked back to an existing case, at least in my environment.

Comment: Thank you very much - it's working with Jenkins plugins! I can live for now without a manual import ;)